# Extension of $\mu$ to a measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\Bbb R$ and $\mathscr A:=\{\;[a,b]\bigcap \Bbb Q \;\mid\; a\leqslant b,\quad a,b \in \Bbb Q\}$

Let $\mu: \Bbb R \to[0, \infty]$ with $\mu([a,b]\bigcap \Bbb Q)=\begin{cases}1,  & \text{if a=b,} \\\infty, & \text{otherwise.}  \end{cases}$

Give an extension  of $\mu$ to a measure $\beta$ on $\sigma(\mathscr A)$? Is $\beta$ unique?

---

How do I find $\beta$? The $\sigma$-Algebra on $\mathscr A$ is $\sigma(\mathscr A)$ = $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: This is just the counting measure.

Comment: are there other measures or is the counting measure the only one? If so how can one prove its uniqueness?

Comment: It's the only one by the additivity property.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the extension is the "[Counting Measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure)" $$\beta(E)=\#E=\text{number of elements in E} .$$